# Regarding SVD, the shape problem I am having for sigma

Tags: svd

I am trying to reduce the dimention of my dataset using SVD. But having error with the size.
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7,7) into shape (199,7)
Could you please check my code. If it is wrong way, please suggest a way to use SVD for dimention reduction. Thanks

```
`from numpy import diag
from numpy import zeros
from scipy.linalg import svd
# defining our data
print(X)

# we will calculate Singular-value decomposition of our X from this API,
U, s, VT = svd(X)

#we need to  create m x n Sigma matrix to use, So it is taking first 2 elements from our X
Sigma = zeros((X.shape[0], X.shape[1]))

# According to formula sigma has to be populated  with n x n diagonal matrix, So we have diag(s), s came from SVD
Sigma[:X.shape[0], :X.shape[0]] = diag(s)

# Telling the number of elements
n_elements = 2
Sigma = Sigma[:, :n_elements]
VT = VT[:n_elements, :]

# we will reconstruct our data with name X_new. 
X_new = U.dot(Sigma.dot(VT))
print(X_new)

# Calculating the transform using sigma and U from SVD
transform = U.dot(Sigma)
print(transform)

#using the transform came from SVD for our data
X_transformed = X_new.dot(VT.T)
print(X_transformed)`
```

My data is 199 raws and 7 columns. I used standard scaler as well, so it is now array. I just took the code from the net, I have no experience with SVD. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To maximise your chances of an answer, make your question easy for responders to try out. (1) Create a MINIMAL reproducible example. i.e. with just a few rows and columns of data, not all 199x7. (2) Include this minimal data within the python code, at the beginning. (At present you are just printing X, which would be an error if someone ran the code.) Make sure that someone can copy your code, paste it into Python, and get the error you are facing. (3) Paste in the exact _text_ of the error message you are seeing.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how SVD works. To perform dimensionality reduction with the regular SVD, you do not project back to the original feature space. MWE:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.random((199, 7))  # (199, 7)
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=True)
X_PCA = np.dot(U[:, :3], np.diag(s[:3]))  # (199, 3)
```

If you now multiply by `v[:, :3].T`, you will get back to your original feature space... And (199, 7) matrix dimension. Because how would you get your original features and reduce their number at the same time? The difference here is that it has the same number of features, but *reduced rank* - basically, it is "less noisy".

The above is an SVD-based implementation of PCA (barring centering of `X`), and you get your first three principal components. Take a look also at [scipy's TruncatedSVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#truncated-singular-value-decomposition-and-latent-semantic-analysis). The whole point of using this family of algorithms is to retain information/remove noise, not to keep the original features. For more information on SVD and PCA, see an excellent answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/134283). It is *technically* possible to use PCA for feature **selection** by using e.g. normalized sum of weights for first few components (more explanation can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27310)). But once again, it is probably not the best tool for the job.

Oh and as a side note - keep track of features/samples, different implementations rely on different notations. As-is, your dataset has 7 features and 199 samples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, yes I have no idea about SVD, I just need to reduce the dimentions using SVD in python from scratch. So is it from scratch? or is there a way to do it without np.linalg.svd(). Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @MukhammadyusufYuldashevKobul Your implementation uses `scipy.linalg.svd`, which is pretty much the same. There is a way to do it in pure Python, but I mean, if you want to go that low level, why are you using Python in the first place? Sounds like a terrible idea. I wrote an SVD implementation in C++ a while ago, but at this point in time, it is almost certainly reinventing the wheel, with bugs lurking everywhere and (likely) a significant performance loss. If you are concerned about the dependency hell, `numpy` is one library you should worry about the least, you are going to use it anyway.

Comment: The code above reduces dimensions to 3 features. This might not be what you want, but it is hard to tell from your description alone, and I am almost certain it could run into an XY problem eventually. Please describe the *actual* problem you are having (e.g. I want to run so-and-so algorithm and am running out of memory, so I was thinking about dimensionality reduction) for people to be able to help you more efficiently.

Comment: aha, it was school assigment and was written so. Anyway, I got it thanks for your help.

Comment: @MukhammadyusufYuldashevKobul Ah, fair enough. Well then, I advise reading on linked answers on stats.SE, they should help you understand these concepts better.